# How to get min and max value of member in list in one pass?

Tags: python, max, min

I can use `functools.reduce` or `min` / `max` to get min and max of members in a list. But to get both in one pass I need to write a loop:

```
from functools import reduce

class foo:
    def __init__(self,value): self.value = value
    
x = []
x.append(foo(1))
x.append(foo(2))
x.append(foo(3))

min_value = reduce(lambda a,b: a if a.value < b.value else b,x).value
max_value = reduce(lambda a,b: a if a.value > b.value else b,x).value

print(min_value)
print(max_value)

min_value2 = min(x,key=lambda a: a.value).value
max_value2 = max(x,key=lambda a: a.value).value

print(min_value2)
print(max_value2)

min_value3 = x[0].value
max_value3 = x[0].value
for f in x:
    if f.value < min_value3: min_value3 = f.value
    if f.value > max_value3: max_value3 = f.value
    
print(min_value3)
print(max_value3)
```

Is it possible to get `min` and `max` in one pass without writing a plain loop?

Comment: I'm not sure it will be very clean when using a lambda, but you could pass a tuple as your aggregator in the `reduce`, where the first value is the min and the second the max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a tuple as your aggregator. Something like this maybe?

```
min_value, max_value = reduce(lambda a, b: 
  (a[0] if a[0].value < b.value else b, a[1] if a[1].value > b.value else b), 
  x, 
  (x[0], x[1]))
```

The output should be a tuple where the first is the minimum and the second the maximum.

Example in the REPL, demonstrating that the objects requested are returned, and that the values are correct:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self,value): self.value = value
...
>>> ls = [Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3)]
>>> min_value, max_value = reduce(lambda a, b: (a[0] if a[0].value < b.value else b, a[1] if a[1].value > b.value else b), ls, (ls[0], ls[1]))
>>> min_value
<__main__.Foo object at 0x10bd20940>
>>> min_value.value
1
>>> max_value.value
3
```

For what it's worth, though, I think it's a little clearer if you use a helper function. In this way it's easier to think cleanly about what your accumulator is (your Tuple) and how you're doing the comparison and using `reduce()`.

```
from typing import Tuple
from functools import reduce


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, value): self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.value}"


def min_max(accumulator: Tuple[Foo, Foo], element: Foo) -> Tuple[Foo, Foo]:
    minimum, maximum = accumulator
    return (minimum if minimum.value < element.value else element,
            maximum if maximum.value > element.value else element)


ls = [Foo(x) for x in range(0, 4)]  # Or however you construct this list
minimum, maximum = reduce(min_max, ls, (ls[0], ls[0]))
print(f"{minimum=} {maximum=}")
```

Yielding:

```
minimum=0 maximum=3
```

Comment: As written, get a `SyntaxError: expected 'else' after 'if' expression`.

Comment: @oda I fixed the issues after testing.

Comment: Works, needs an `x` instead of `ls` though

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `__lt__` function, and then use `min()` and `max()` as you normally would:

```py
from functools import reduce

class foo:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
    
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.value < other.value 
    
x = []
x.append(foo(1))
x.append(foo(2))
x.append(foo(3))

min_value, max_value = min(x), max(x)
print(min_value.value, max_value.value)
```

This outputs:

```py
1 3
```

---

This is a one-liner, but strictly speaking it's not one-pass. You can use `reduce()` for that. Other answerers have described methods that use `reduce()` as well, but defining `__lt__` makes the syntax much cleaner, in my opinion:

```py
min_value, max_value = reduce(lambda a, b: (min(a[0], b), max(a[1], b)), x, (x[0], x[0]))
print(min_value.value, max_value.value)
```

Comment: That counts as two passes, since `min` and `max` each consume the input separately.

Comment: This does return a correct result... but I don't think it's 'in one pass'.

Comment: Hmm, fair point. Let me think about this a bit more. I like defining the `__lt__` function because you can easily use it for other things: sorting algorithms, heaps, etc.

Comment: @NathanielFord -- Edited. Let me know what you think.

Comment: I think it's a worthwhile point that `__lt__` is useful - though I'm not entirely sure that making a min/max function call is cheaper or equivalently cheap as using inequalities.

Comment: The problem with defining `__lt__` is that you aren't necessarily picking one value or another. Given `(cur_min, cur_max)` and `x`, you aren't picking one or the other; you need to pick one of *three* values `(x, cur_max)`, `(cur_min, x)`, or `(cur_min, cur_max)`.